# How to slice association rules DataFrame in R Server?

Tags: sql-server, r, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016

I have below code to process association rules inside R Server. This Works totally fine outside R Server, but when I adapt the codes to run inside SQL Server 2016 I get error.

"Target" in this case is what the PartID I want to filter.

```
SELECT BK_PARTID, CorpOrderID INTO #TEMP FROM ARTransactions 
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM #TEMP'
DECLARE @RScript NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'
library(arules)

TransactionsDataSet = as(split(StoreTransactions[,"BK_PartID"], StoreTransactions[,"CorpOrderID"]),"transactions")

Target = 10092007

filtered_rules = apriori(data = TransactionsDataSet, parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.20, minlen = 2),appearance = list(default = "rhs", lhs = c(Target)),control = list(verbose = F))

#filtered_rules = inspect(filtered_rules[1:10])

#filtered_rules <- head(as(sort(filtered_rules, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = NA, by = "confidence"), "data.frame"), 30);

'

EXEC sp_execute_external_script 
@Language = N'R',
@Script = @RScript,
@input_data_1 = @SQLQuery,
@input_data_1_name = N'StoreTransactions',
@parallel = 1,
@output_data_1_name = N'filtered_rules'

WITH RESULT SETS ((Rules VARCHAR(MAX), Support FLOAT, Confidense FLOAT, Lift FLOAT));
```

ERROR:

```
(591112 row(s) affected) Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 14 A 

'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004. Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 14

An external script error occurred: Carregando pacotes exigidos: Matrix

Attaching package: 'arules'

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
%in%, abbreviate, write

Error in asMethod(object) : 10092007 is an unknown item label Calls: source ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> apriori -> as -> asMethod

Error in ScaleR. Check the output for more information. Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Error in ScaleR. Check the output for more information. Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
```

---

OBS. This PART exists in Dataset.

Could not find anything equal and inside RStudio, Works fine.

ANyone has any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Hmm, you say this works fine outside of SQL Server R Services. Outside of SQL Server R, are you using CRAN R? What happens if you were to point RStudio to use the SQL Server R Services: Tools | Global Options | R version. This just to see if there might be an issue with the `arules` package in SQL Server R Services.

Comment: HI! When I say ouside Works fine, I mean in Visual Studio 2015 Works fine with R Client. When I use this embedded, gives this error. I think Arules is working fine, because the code runs when I am not filtering the PARTID. With full result set Works fine. I think, the problem is add this as parameter. I still have to to one test and in case Works, I ll come back saying! TKS!!

Comment: Just decided export everything into a SQL Server table, transform the records and then filter by "PARTID" after process the model. It will work fine because I need all part's anyway.